# User has access to share drive but can't see a certain file, other users can see that file. Any advice?

Tags: windows, share

Like I said in the title, a user has access to our company's Accounting share drive. He's trying to access a file at the share path V:\Accounting\Needthisfile but whenever he attempts to navigate to it, it does not exist according to his system. I tried taking off the file name and navigating to the file manually from the Accounting drive but it was not in the list. He has full access to the other files in the list and this file is the only discrepancy. Other users can see the file just fine.

Any advice?

Comment: Operating system? Most likely a file permission issue.

Comment: Windows 7 locally. Server 2012 R2 if that matters.

Comment: There are just permission, offlinecache and caching issues. I've never seen anything else ...

Answer (score 1):

If access based enumeration is turned on for the file share then users do not see files and folders they don’t have at least read access to. So it could be a permission issue. You can check the effective permissions for a particular user of a file or folder by using the security tab of the file/folder properties.

The other possibility is that the user has turned on offline files and his CSC cache is corrupt. You can check offline files in control panel and turn it off if need be.

This is assuming that you are using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give an exact reason, but the most likely problem is an NTFS permission issue on the file in question. The user who can't see the file probably does not have permission to it.